# Html5 canvas showing an array in a grapich does not turn

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, canvas, graphics

Here you can find the code of my little program.

http://jsfiddle.net/joz8h9hc/

It's aim is to find out how to turn a square that depicts the values of a 2d array, in order to allow visualization of 2d mathematical arrays.

Why it's not turning clockwise or counterclockwise?

```
var canvas=document.getElementById('canvas');
    var ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');
    //GIRADOR
    ctx.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);     
    //FIN GIRADOR
    var array = new Array2D(200,200);
    //MAIN
    for(i=0; i<200; i++)
    {
      for(j=0;j<200; j++)
      {
      array[i][j]=i+j;

          var r,g,b;
      r = array[i][j];
      g=50;
      b=50;
      //La parte de dibujo
      ctx.fillStyle = "rgba("+r+","+g+","+b+",100)";
      ctx.fillRect( i, j, 1, 1 );
          }
    }

    //FUNCTIONS

    function Array2D(NumOfRows,NumOfCols)
    {
    var k=new Array(NumOfRows);
    for (i = 0; i < k.length; ++i)
    k[i] = new Array(NumOfCols);
    return k; 
    }

    function Rotar(){
    //Rotamos el lienzo?
    ctx.rotate(Math.PI / 180);
     ctx.fillStyle = "red";
      ctx.fillRect( -200, -200, 600, 600 );
    for(i=0; i<200; i++)
    {
      for(j=0;j<200; j++)
      {
      array[i][j]=i+j;
      var r,g,b;
      r = array[i][j];
      g=50;
      b=50;
      //La parte de dibujo
      ctx.fillStyle = "rgba("+r+","+g+","+b+",100)";
      ctx.fillRect( i, j, 1, 1 );
      }
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`context.translate` will set your rotation point.  All subsequent drawings will rotate around this point.

Therefore, if you're subsequently drawing a rectangle, the rectangle will be drawn with its top-left corner at your translate point.  The rect will rotate around its own top-left corner.

To rotate a rect around its centerpoint, you would set the x,y of fillRect to -width/2, -height/2.

Also, transformations (translate, rotate) are cumulative so you probably want to wrap your transformations in `context.save` and `context.restore` so subsequent transformations don't interact with previous transformations.

Here's example code and a demo illustrating rotating a rectangle around its centerpoint:

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

// variables to define the rectangle
var x=100;
var y=100;
var width=100;
var height=75;
var radianAngle=0;

// draw the rectangle
rotateSquare();

function rotateSquare(){
  // clear the canvas
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
  // save the unrotated context state
  ctx.save();
  // set the rotation point at the rectangle's centerpoint
  ctx.translate(x+width/2,y+height/2);
  // set the rotation angle
  ctx.rotate(radianAngle);
  // draw the rectangle
  ctx.fillRect(-width/2,-height/2,width,height);
  ctx.strokeRect(-width/2,-height/2,width,height);
  // restore the context to its unrotated state
  ctx.restore();
}

$("#test").click(function(){
  // reset the angle
  radianAngle+=Math.PI/60;
  // call rotateSquare
  rotateSquare();
});
```

```css
canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="test">Rotate</button><br>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: I works and turns properlly now. Not from its center, but from its 1,1 point, due to being an array being draw each time you turn the square